# how to return the number when the button is clicked

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

My question is when the number is get from the an arraylist, for example
`JNumber.size()=10`;

```
    for(int a=0;a<JNumber.size();a++)
    {
         btnNumber= new JNumber(""+(a+1));
         btnNumber.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 10));
         panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));
         panel.add(btnNumber, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
```

Then how to return the number when the button is clicked?

> Output:
>
> Number 2 is clicked.

Comment: Can you include the definition of panel and btnNumber?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in an ActionListener.
Using the code given, this should work in your case:

If you want a text shown which is not only numeric then initialize the button with the specific text and set the actioncommand of the button to the actual number. (See below.)

```
btnNumber= new JNumber(""+(a+1));
btnNumber.setActionCommand(""+(a+1));    
btnNumber.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton button = (JButton)evt.getSource();
        int num = Integer.parseInt(button.getActionCommand());
        System.out.println(num);
      }
    });
```

Comment: i try to run with this code, but come out with this error when i clicked the Button 1'Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"' java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1"   what is this mean?

Comment: The meaning of this is, that we try to parse a text to a number, which is actually not a number, so for example Integer.parseInt("asdf"); will throw a NumberFormatException. In your case this is only possible if the text on the button is not a numeric one. You should check if you have something like a single space before or after the number on the button.

Comment: its works. Thanks a lot! how if i want "Number 1"  b seen on the Jbutton. how should i write the code?

Comment: I updated the code above this should work for you. Btw.. please mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example hope it helps. Basically just add `JButton`s to `JPanel`, add `ActionListener` to each `JButton`, add `JPanel` to `JFrame`, after clicking a button a `println()` will be executed with the ActionCommand of the `JButton` (+1 to @Pr0gr4mm3r for `setActionCommand()` usage):

[image]

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class ButtonsTest {

    public ButtonsTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));//create gridlayput to hold buttons

        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                //display action command of jbutton
                String ac = ((JButton) ae.getSource()).getActionCommand();
                System.out.println(ac);
                //display full test in Jbutton
                //String text = ((JButton) ae.getSource()).getText();
                //System.out.println(text);
            }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            JButton b = new JButton("No: " + String.valueOf((i + 1)));
            b.setActionCommand(String.valueOf((i + 1)));
            b.addActionListener(al);
            panel.add(b);
        }

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //set L&F and create UI on EDT
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {//set L&F
                    for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // If Nimbus is not available, you can set the GUI to another look and feel.
                }
                //create UI
                new ButtonsTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `btnNumber` as `final` and add an `ActionListener` to it:

```
btnNumber.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Number " + btnNumber.getText() + " is clicked");
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't see any need to declare the button as final, each button could share the same action listener and extract it self from the event source and then use your suggestion - IMHO